# extending an already asked question

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

I have a very similiar question to [Multiple Reverse DNS Entries?](https://serverfault.com/questions/65781/multiple-reverse-dns-entries)

Is there a way to extend this question or should I just ask a new one?

Comment: It would be easier to determine if you could add a little detail.

Or you can just ask a new Question; at the bottom reference the old and a brief reason why you think your Question is different/extended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the question you reference doesn't answer your question then ask a new one. You may want to reference the earlier question and say why it doesn't help you when doing so.

Answer (score 7):

If the old question heavily overlaps with your new question aside from some minor details, then another option would be to simply add a bounty to the old question along with some comments asking for clarification of a particular detail.  But the bounty system, does require you already have some reputation on the site.